# How to return an image as an IActionResult from an Image/Bitmap object

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core

I am generating a Barcode image using the barcodelib library + the System.Drawing.Common package available in .Net Core.

I want to return the image to the users in their browser as a plain image (or as a download) but I seem to not find a good way to do so.

What I've tried:

```
var barcode = new Barcode().Encode(TYPE.CODE128, reference);
usuing (var outputStream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    barcode.Save(outputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(outputStream, "image/jpeg");
}
```

This gives an exception, saying that the stream is closed.

It can be fixed by removing the using but isn't it bad? doesn't the streams stay in memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the `using` block on the `outputStream`. The stream is being closed/disposed before it can be used by the response.

The `FileResult` will close the stream when it is finished using it.

```
var barcode = new Barcode().Encode(TYPE.CODE128, reference);
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
barcode.Save(outputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return File(outputStream, "image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score 3):

While `FileResult` will close the stream, frankly, I don't like depending on some external thing cleaning up after me, and at least to my eyes, the code just looks wrong newing up a `MemoryStream` outside of a `using` block and just letting it go without ever explicitly closing it.

There's an overload of `File` that accepts a byte array, so you can simply move your return outside of your `using` block.

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    var barcode = new Barcode().Encode(TYPE.CODE128, reference);
    barcode.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
```

It's a bit of personal preference, admittedly, but that just looks cleaner and more "correct" to me.

Comment: It does indeed look cleaner, I also was a bit "triggered" by the fact that I can't clean my own stuff. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that the result is no longer "streamed" when you do it this way, though. However, the only real downside to that is that it must be loaded into memory entirely first. Given that you're *already* doing that by using a `MemoryStream`, it's inconsequential. However, if your stream was coming from the filesystem or such *and* not already being loaded fully into memory (image ops and such would require loading into memory), it would be more efficient to pass the stream directly to the result. Just something to be aware of.